# Rails API object show full attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got this object that I need to see the full details from.  But all my console outputs is:

```
#<Calendly::Invitee:62820 uuid="1b8d2606-3339-40bd-bbb4-edc2dbe32f77", name="((Redacted for privacy))", status="canceled", email="((redacted for privacy))", ..>
```

Note that this is an object obtained from an API, not a typical Rails model object.

I don't know what the keys are for the missing attributes, otherwise I would look them up individually.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.  The desired method is "instance_values"

So I got all the info like this:

```
invitee.instance_values.each do |field, val|
    puts field
    puts val
    puts ""
end
```